# Як "дорожить репутацией" з російської?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як "дорожить репутацией" з російської? Коли твоя репутація важить...

Словник ABBYY Lingvo [не містить перекладу цілого словосполучення і натомість пропонує перекласти окремо слова як «дорожити» і «репутація»](http://www.lingvo.ua/ru/Translate/ru-uk/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99641/discussion-on-question-by-kosarar-----).

Answer (score 10):

Окрім банальних «[дорожити *кимось/чимось*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=24222&page=813)» і *розм.* «[дорожитися *кимось/чимось*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=24223&page=813)», російське «дорожить» має такі [переклади](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=rus&dicts=all&highlight=on):

- надавати значення *комусь/чомусь*;
- не могти скласти ціну *комусь/чомусь*;
- складати велику ціну на *когось/щось*;
- цінувати *когось/щось*;
- шанувати *когось/щось*.

Недоліками цих варіантів є те, що російське «дорожить репутацией» зазвичай має на увазі «дорожити **своєю** репутацією». В той час як «надавати значення репутації», «цінувати репутацію», «шанувати репутацію» тощо такої конотації не мають, можна цінувати не лише власну репутацію, а й репутацію потенційних контрагентів (тяжіти до взаємодії з репутованими контрагентами) — і, власне, саме це спливає мені на думку в першу чергу з цими словами.

Тому, якщо перекладати за змістом — в сенсі «саме про свою репутацію», я пропоную:

- «берегти/оберігати репутацію»; наприклад, в перекладах твору «Доктор Сон» С. Кінга:

  - російський: «[не сам. Мне все же дорога моя репутация](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=30115&p=89)»,
  - український: «[не я особисто, я мушу берегти репутацію](http://read-online.in.ua/read/doktor_son/132)»;
- «дбати за/про репутацію»;
- «підтримувати репутацію»;
- «піклуватися за/про репутацію»;
- «стояти за репутацією»;
- *розм. експр.* «трястися над репутацією».

Answer (score 6):

В [Російсько-українському словнику](https://r2u.org.ua/data/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2%20%281959%29.pdf) сталих виразів (ст. 163 ПДФ) знайшов дуже гарний вислів "**шанувати свою славу**" (з прикладу "Він не шанує своєї слави"). Однак, напевно, такий переклад не завжди буде влучним. Можу припустити, що ще можна сказати "[пильнувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/pyljnuvaty) за своєю репутацією".